# Does onApplicationStart execute after a timeout?

Tags: coldfusion

In ColdFusion 9, when the application reaches its maximum timeout and the memory space is dumped, does the application get rebuilt (i.e. does onApplicationStart get called)?

If so, at which point timeout or on the next page call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the application times out then onApplicationStart() is called with the *next* request to the application. But every request to the application resets the timer. In other words for the application to "time out" it has to be idle (servicing zero requests) for the length of the time specified in as the application timeout property.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see for yourself that the onApplicationStart() method has just fired, you can do something like this at the end of the method:

```
<cfscript>
// GOES WITHIN THE ON APPLICATION START METHOD
APPLICATION.AppSettings.ThisDomain = CGI.HTTP_HOST;
if (APPLICATION.AppSettings.ThisDomain == "YourAwesomeDomain.com") {
    APPLICATION.AppSettings.ProductionMode = true;
} else if (APPLICATION.AppSettings.ThisDomain == "127.0.0.1:8500") {
    APPLICATION.AppSettings.ProductionMode = false;
} else {
    abort;
}
// STALL THE APP IF IT IS IS DEVELOPMENT MODE
if (APPLICATION.AppSettings.ProductionMode == true) {
    writeoutput("<h1>Just FIRED UP the APPLICATION in DEVELOPMENT mode.</h1>");
    writeoutput("<a href="">continue.</a>");
    abort;
}
</cfscript>
```

If you timeout the application after 5 seconds and the hit this page with a frequency greater than 5 seconds, you'll see the "just fired up" message.  If you hit the page with a frequency less than 5 seconds, you won't see this message.

You can extend this to view when a new session is created too:

```
<cfscript>
// GOES WITHIN THE ON SESSION START METHOD
// STALL THE APP IF IT IS IS DEVELOPMENT MODE
if (APPLICATION.AppSettings.ProductionMode == true) {
    writeoutput("<h1>Just FIRED UP a new SESSION in DEVELOPMENT mode.</h1>");
    writeoutput("<a href="">continue.</a>");
    abort;
}
</cfscript>
```